# How to hide DataTables export button if no data?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am doing project in laravel. I have implemented DataTables as,

**blade.php**

```
<table id="userprofaneword-table" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.report.profaneword.table.id') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.report.profaneword.table.user') }}</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          @foreach($profaneData as $profaneUser)
               <tr>
                   <td>{{$profaneUser->user->id ?? '---'}}</td>
                   <td>{{$profaneUser->user->first_name ?? '---'}}
                   </td>
               </tr>
          @endforeach
     </tbody>
</table>
```

**Scripts**

```
{{ Html::script("https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js") }}
{{ Html::script("js/backend/plugin/datatables/dataTables-extend.js") }}

{{ Html::script("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js") }}
{{ Html::script("https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js") }}
{{ Html::script("https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js") }}

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#userprofaneword-table').DataTable({
            "dom": "Bfrtip",
            "lengthChange": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "searching": true,
            "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            "language": {
                "searchPlaceholder": "Search",
            },
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "extend": 'excelHtml5',
                    "text": 'Export User Profanity Report',
                    "className":"btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right",
                    "exportOptions": {
                     "columns": ":not(:last-child)",
                    }
                }
            ],
            "select": true,
            "searchDelay": 500
        });
    });
</script>
```

Every thing works fine. I can export data from table, I just want **hide export button if there is no data** coming from controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you want to react on filtering and so on. And you just want to make the button invisible, not break the DOM layout. You can use `drawCallback` and set `visibility` according to the presence of rows :

```js
drawCallback: function() {
  var hasRows = this.api().rows({ filter: 'applied' }).data().length > 0;
  $('.buttons-excel')[0].style.visibility = hasRows ? 'visible' : 'hidden'
}
```

Here is a demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/okednaqg/**

Answer (score 1):

```
var table = $('#userprofaneword-table').DataTable();
var buttons = table.buttons( ['.edit', '.delete'] );

if ( table.rows( { selected: true } ).indexes().length === 0 ) {
  buttons.disable();
}
else {
buttons.enable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery to disable/enable the button based on the row count. Here's an example where the CSV export is disabled if the row count is zero. You could tie this to [rowCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) option or a custom event.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable(); 
if ( ! table.data().count() ) {
    table.buttons( $('a.dt-button.csv') ).disable();
}
```