# jQuery datatable export to excel with my own custom button

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jquery datatable and I want to use datatable's export to excel feature. But I don't want to show export excel button of datatable instead of this, I want to show my own button and call datatable's export to excel function.

With below code I was able to export the excel sucessfully but as I said above I want to export the excel when user clicked my custom button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "info": false,
            searching: false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5'
                }
            ]
            });
        });
```

I have added click handler using below thread button i don't ant to show datatble's export button. I want make those buttons invisible.
[How to call Datatable csv button from custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515559/how-to-call-datatable-csv-button-from-custom-button)

Comment: [Add a click handler](https://api.jquery.com/click/) to your button and call the `DataTable()` function when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply kmoser. I have updated my question But still i can see the datatable's export buttons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166257/how-to-hide-datatables-export-button-if-no-data/. Alternately, add custom CSS to hide those elements.